# Heap for fast insertion and deletion O(log n)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, search

I'm trying to find an algorithm that has a few properties described below:

- Use an array as storage (cache friendly).
- Only store unsigned integers.
- No values are associated.
- Insert and delete  an ith item should be in order of O(log n) time.
- Keep the structure stable so elements can be deleted when it is traversed.
- Order and lookup of individual items is not important nor Max or Min.

There are a number of solutions for this kind of problems. 
One very common is red/black trees. I don't like trees for this problem due to the fact I would have to use dynamic memory among other thins (like storing pointers and associated values I don't need).

The other option I was thinking of is to use is a binary heap. It is designed to delete min/max element fast so is suitable for priority queues. In my case I would need some extended version that allows deletion of an arbitrary item in the heap.
Is it possible to do deletion in log(n) time. It is been mentioned in the web that if you have the position in the array it is the case. However I could not find a proof that this is correct.
The other thing is the stability during deletion.
If the answer is no, what would you suggest?

Comment: As a negative proof: Using an array if you delete the nth element you either have to track the gap someway (not nice) or collapse the space. Collapsing the space is Order(n-i) operations which tends to Order(n/2) for random deletions which is O(n).  There are red/back methods which use a second index array which are probably O(log n).

Comment: What does "stable" mean?  "Keep the structure stable so elements can be deleted when it is traversed."

Comment: The usage is, during a traversal (may be using iterators) an item can be selected for deletion. Then the traversal can continue deleting items without starting from the beginning. This is a nice to have, may be not needed though depending on the structure and chosen algorithm.

Comment: Here's how to do it: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/9-BinTree/:

Comment: Thanks, deletion of K element proof of taking log(n) is good. I will take a look to rest of the html files.

Comment: What is the `i` in "ith item"? Do you assign the item an index when you add it to the container so that you can later delete it? When you add an item, do you specify where it goes? Or do you just need to be able to delete "the current item" during an iteration?

Comment: ith is an integer value between 0 and n representing a positon from another array. I want to represent a subset of an existing array.
To you second question, not yet, but probably doing it. So in each rotation I will have to update the value on the corresponding index. Probably I will be using another array with the positions (depending on the peformance). And lastly, I need to delete the current item and continue. BTW, This is one solution I have in mind, R/B trees, 23 trees or hash tables may be also valid solutions. This will be part of a set of policies for new container we are creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do deletion on O(lg n) time on random element in a Heap.

How? Suppose this is your heap:

```
                   4
                 /   \
                10   20
               /  \  ...
              30  40  ...
             /  \   ......
            50  60
```

suppose you wanna remove 10, then (as this is a Min-Heap) you get the smallest child of 10 and put into his place, then you restart beginning from 10's smallest child (30) and brings 30's smallest child up (50).

If you heap is correctly built, then the properties will be held as this method runs.

In fact, this is nothing more than a Heapify that doesn't start from the root.

```
        4                    4                    4 
      /   \                /   \                /   \
   [10]   20              30   20              30   20
   /  \   ...    =>      /  \   ...    =>     /  \   ...
  30  40   ...        [30]  40   ...         50  40   ...
 /  \    ......       /  \     ......       /  \    ......
50  60               50  60              [50]  60
```

Comment: Correct, but note that it reorders the array, so the iteration is not stable and any information you had about the index of a given element is invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, then you do not need to be able to look up items by value and you don't care what order they're in?

If that's the case then you should just put them in an array starting at the beginning.  If you have to delete an item in the middle, then just swap it with the item and the end and then delete it from there.

It's also easy to do this while iterating through the array.  When you delete an item you just don't increment the position, because the next item to visit was swapped into the place of the item you deleted.

Comment: For one of the policies I need this is a perfect solution. Thanks!
And it is O(1). I did not see it being so simple :-)